# Installing missing symbol file libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2 on Linux Mint 17

Tags: symbols, libc, libstdc++

I am trying to execute a cellular automata program on Linux Mint 17, and I get the following error:

```
./simu: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have libstdc++ installed, and there is no file in there containing the name libstdc++-libc.

I have checked many other solutions, but nothing seems to work. I am therefore wondering what I should do to find and install the missing file. This is for a school project, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is useful to give a brief description of already tried solutions, this is useful in order to track the real problem

Answer (score 2):

**Please provide more details**

You can obtain useful proofs about your binary (simu) with the `file` command:

```
file path/to/the/simu
```

You can also double check with `ldd` the exact name of the libraries the binary is looking for:

```
ldd path/to/the/simu
```

Please provide the output of the previous commands in order to help answering your question.

**Meanwhile, one possible answer could be..**

I suppose the binary has been compiled on a RedHat/Fedora/Centos by using their compat-lib* package (that provides the `libstdc++-libc` lib).

I think/suppose there is not the same `compat-*` package and library in Mint/Ubuntu, but being compiled with such a library, perhaps, it should work by creating a proper symbolic link, by hand, in library path. The symbolic link should point to one of the installed `libstdc++` dynamic libraries in your system)

e.g., you can create a link from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.?` where ? is the smaller version number that you find in your system.
Command example (you have to adapt it for sure):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2
```

There are also cases (depending the binary is compiled on 32 or 64 bits) where you need to change the path `x86_64-linux-gnu` into `i386-linux-gnu`. You have to try and adapt to your case.

This is an hypothetical rough hack, no guarantees :-) in fact I'm just curious.

**Cleaner way**

In order to not pollute your OS/system with links, you can create a new folder, name it "customlibs",  in the same place you have the program/binary.

You can create the links for each not-matching library filenames, inside that folder, e.g.:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./customlibs/libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2
```

Then, in order to execute the program, open a terminal and from cli change the `LD_LIBRARY` enviroment variable with this command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/absolute/path/to/customlibs
```

in this way, the system looks in `customlibs` too for libs.

In the same terminal, execute the program:

```
./simu
```

In this way you don't mess with the system.

**You need to be very lucky**

It is quite simpler to perform the job in "Cleaner way" when copying the required libraries from the system the binary has been compiled in.

It is also a more reliable way, I have performed this few times.
The hack we are performing now, linking with the current system libs, is a bit "harder". Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting back to me. From the first command I got

Comment: simu: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.0.0, not stripped
and for the second I got  linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77a7000)
 libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2 => not found
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7717000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7566000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77a8000)
I will try the linking command next. Can the linking command cause any problems for the rest of the system.

Comment: First, you can note that you have a 32 (386) bit binary, so you need to link the /lib/i386-linux-gnu libs and not the x64 ones. Also note that you lack both libstdc++-libc6.1-1.so.2 and libm.so.6.so, the second is quite strange, please check if you have this library installed. Usually when you do not overwrite files that are already there, you break nothing but it's a bit messy. I'll add a suggestion to my answer about a cleaner way to create the link. Please consider that these are hacks that work better when you copy in a folder/use the libraries from the old OS where the binary come from

Comment: added a "cleaner way" section, let's try.. but you have to be very lucky. It could be very useful to know the distro name this binary comes from, or, in the case you have access to that system, if you can copy files from that system. Regads

Comment: Please update the thread with the final outcome (success/failure), it is the most important contribution ;-)

Comment: about libm.so.6.so, is this lacking or not? I am not sure I red well  the ldd output (no newlines)

Comment: I found another application that does what I need, so the issue is resolved. In any case, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ehm, is another way to run the simu program? or another program to do the same job of simu? In the first case, sharing may be useful to other guys...